# How to map in Python Protein IDs to Protein names? ( and then to gene IDs)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapping, bioinformatics, biopython

I am using the String database for protein links to create a protein interaction network. The protein ids come with an annotation file for protein names, however, not all proteins get mapped when I map from one file to another (I used a dictionary for protein ids example: Protein 1: xxxx, Protein 2:xxxx as one entry) Is there a python library or package that allows me to actually run my list of protein IDs to protein names to cover for the unmapped ones? (and subsequently, I would appreciate help with mapping protein names to gene IDs using GWAS catalogue).
Any help would be much much valued! Thanks

Comment: Could you give a [mre] of what you're trying to achieve?